# Receive buffer data is missing after first read in TcpServer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, tcp, tcpserver

I try to send data shorter than 255 length in Client side.

I try to send data with this protocol :

```
Lenghth+String
Byte+string
sample :
string = ABCD
sentdata = 4ABCD
```

here is my server side code:

```
procedure TfrmServer.tcpsrvr1Accept(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
  var
  a : array of byte;
  I : Cardinal;
  mystr : string;
  b,Len : Byte;
begin
  ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(b,1,0);// first try : get lenght
  Len := b;
  SetLength(a,Len+1);
  mmoRerult.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(now) + ' Data Len ' +
                  IntToStr(Len));
  ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(a,Len,0); // second try : this lone is not worked.

  mystr := '';
  for I := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    mystr := mystr + Chr(a[i]);
  end;
  mmoRerult.Lines.Add(mystr);
  //Creating a stream
  mmoRerult.Lines.Add('--------------------');

end;
```

Problem is if I read all data in first possible `first try`, But if I read data in `second try` is not possible,not possible mean is the data is not correct, I think the read pointer is get front, but how can I reset.

And `ClientSocket.BytesReceived` don't give me count of byte received before read.

How can I fix this problem, Please don't tell me read 255 byte in first I know this way.

Comment: Don't use unsigned types for loop variables. Painful looping to Count-1 when Count is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the data into the pointer rather than the buffer. Fix it like this:

```
ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(pointer(a)^,Len,0);
```

It would be much easier to read directly into an AnsiString variable mind you.

```
var
  str: AnsiString;
....
SetLength(str, Len);
ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(pointer(str)^,Len,0);
```

Comment: Dynamic array and string are really pointers. So you need to de-reference the pointer to get to the buffer.

Comment: Or `ShortString`, perhaps? OP's data structure is Turbo Pascal string in the fact.